# Jenkins Multijob that run jobs running on multiple machines

Tags: jenkins

I have job A that run in parallel on 3 slaves and Job B that run on other 3 slaves, to do that I'm using the Node parameter which hold list of slaves but only one slave can be set as default.
Now I want to create a multi job that will run both jobs in parallel, how should I do that ?
Also how can I tell each one of the child jobs on which machines it should run ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear answer for you, but this sounds like a time to use [Labels](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Nodelabelsforagents)